# Unable to get the "extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask" property to work in a Universal Windows Platform application using VS 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
Page
x:Class="App7.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App7"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions">
```

```
  <TextBox extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="9a9a-a9a*"
                 Header="Text box with Mask 9a9a-a9a* (9 allows from 0 to 9, a allow from a to Z and * allows both a and 9)"
                 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                 Style="{StaticResource MaskedTextBoxStyle}" />

  <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="+1999-9999"
                 extensions:TextBoxMask.PlaceHolder=" "
                 Header="Text box with Mask +1999-9999 and placeHolder as space (placeholder represents the characters the user can change on runtime)"
                 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                 Style="{StaticResource MaskedTextBoxStyle}" />

  <TextBox Grid.Row="2"
                 extensions:TextBoxMask.CustomMask="5:[1-5],c:[a-c]"
                 extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="a5c-5c*9"
                 Header="Text box with CustomMask in case you want to define your own variable character like a,9 and * , mask: a5c-5c*9, 5: [1-5], c: [a-c]"
                 HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
                 Style="{StaticResource MaskedTextBoxStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

The code shown above comes straight out of Microsoft's example of how to use the TextBoxMask.Mask property in a UWP application.

Yet I get the error message:  "The name "TextBoxMask" does not exist in the namespace using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions" for each occurrence of  "extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask"

I think I'm doing everything correctly, following Microsoft's documentation and using their sample program. My system meets the requirements to use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions in Visual Studio 2017:

1. I used "Manage NuGet Packages …" to 
   install Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions into Visual Studio
2. I Have Windows version 10.0.18262, which is higher than the minimum required version of 10.0.16299.
3. I Created a simple UWP app, in Visual Studio 2017 using the example from Microsoft, without making a single change to the code in the example.
4. I peaked at the source code at https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/TextBoxMask, seeing that the controls I want are, in fact, present.

I have exhausted all of my resources to solve this technical problem.  If I'm doing something wrong, I'm simply not seeing my mistake.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue and it seems that there is nothing wrong with the steps you described.Is clean->build useful? Can you provide your sample for us to reproduce?

Comment: The problem was operator error, my fault. I installed Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp instead of Microsoft.Toolkit.Upw.UI.

Comment: Glad you solved it.You can post the answer directly that would be helpful for other communities .

Comment: Microsoft.Toolkit.Upw.UI does not exist.